# What insect left this?

Tags: insect

This appeared in our home beneath a window, on top of a baseboard, over the last two days. Any idea what this could be? Would we need an exterminator? We are new homeowners in the Northeast. Thanks!
[image: what insect left these?]

Here is another photo: [image: photo2]

Here is a photo of a nearby windowsill: [image: photo3]

Comment: It is difficult to say from the photo. But is mayfly season in the Northeast.

Comment: Is there an additional photo that would help? This is in the interior, by the way. We are in southern CT.

Comment: I added a new photo. Let me know if you have any insights.

Comment: Just added another photo of a nearby windowsill. What could this be?

Comment: All I can see looks like wood debris carpenter ants and termites can cause damage that can cause this kind of mess.

Comment: The third photo (windowsill) looks more like damp/mould to me than anything else. (I have no clue on the other pics.)